# "Update Values: Items" Prompt

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula pasted in a cell:

`=IF(AND(B2<>"",H3="",L3="",P3="",T3="",X3="",AB3="",AF3="",AJ3="",AN3="",AR3=""),MATCH(A3,Action Items!A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(A3,'Action Items'!A:A,0),IF(C3="Special",IF(INDEX('Special Criteria - Action Items'!A:I,MATCH(A3,'Special Criteria - Action Items'!H:H,0),1)="Yes",MATCH(A3,'Action Items'!A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(A3,'Action Items'!A:A,0),""),IF(OR(H3="Yes",L3="Yes",P3="Yes",T3="Yes",X3="Yes",AB3="Yes",AF3="Yes",AJ3="Yes",AN3="Yes",AR3="Yes"),MATCH(A3,'Action Items'!A:A,0)&":"&MATCH(A2,'Action Items'!A:A,0),"")))`

Everytime I press enter, a box appears stating "Update Values: Items", and prompts me to select a file.  From reading online, I see that this is caused from referencing a closed workbook; however, I'm only referencing sheets within the same workbook in this formula.  I do have several versions of this workbook, so there are workbooks on file with the same tab names.

From process of elimination, it's the 'Action Items" tab that's causing the error.

Upon pushing enter, I'm getting a #NAME error.  I'm wondering what I've done to prompt Excel to interpret the sheets as outsider references? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You have `...MATCH(A3,Action Items!A:A,0)...` it should be `...MATCH(A3, 'Action Items'!A:A, 0)...`. (first occurrence)

Comment: Aye, such a silly mistake.  Thanks! @Jeeped

Comment: If it's alright with you, I'll vote to close this as a simple typographical error that is unlikely to be reproduced.

Comment: Absolutely! @Jeeped